# Plot points below a certain value

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I would like to plot only the points which d1 is less than 0.2 for them.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=data$d1, y=data$d2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = mydata))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the points in your data feeding into `ggplot` function. Please notice that you don't need `data$` in `aes`; you can simply use the variable name. Here, I am using `iris` dataset since you haven't provided your data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris[iris$Sepal.Length<5,], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species))
```

[image]

In your case, it'd be:

```r
ggplot(data[data$d1<0.2,], aes(x=d1, y=d2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = mydata))
```

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot` plots the data you give it. If you only want it to plot a subset of your data, only give it a subset of your data:

```
ggplot(subset(data, d1 < 0.2), aes(x = d1, y = d2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = mydata))
```

Also, don't use `data$column` inside `aes()`--just use unquoted column names.